# I want the data obtained from find table1 to insert into table2 in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I want the data obtained from find table1 to insert into table2

```
$table1= Table1::find($id);
$table2= new Table2();
```

without

```
$table2->field1 = $table1->field1;
$table2->field2 = $table1->field2;
```

where I have multiple fields
How do I use it? to be able to write short code

Answer (score 0):

mean like this?

```
$table1 = Table1::find($id);

Table2::create([
    'field1' => $table1->field1,
    'field2' => $table1->field2,
]);
```

if the fields in table2 are same with table1

```
$table1 = Table1::find($id);

Table2::create($table1->toArray());
```

Comment: create method accepts only array and auto-increment id will the id of table1.

Comment: I was wrong. should have changed first to array on table1, but id in table2 will auto-increment.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has the [replicate()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#replicating-models) function that will do your job.

This is how you can use it:

```
$table1 = Table1::find($id);
$table2 = $table1->replicate();
$table2 = $table2->toArray();
Table2::create($table2);
```

This function will clone your one model data into another object. If you want to change/add/replace any data from the model data then you can also add/modify it:

```
$table1 = Table1::find($id);
$table2 = $table1->replicate()->fill([
    'field_name' => 'value'        // Override any data
    'new_field_name' => 'value'    // Add new field data
]);
$table2 = $table2->toArray();
Table2::create($table2);
```

I hope that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This will create a new entry into same table with changed values. Not as per the requirements .

Comment: Update the answer could you please try that?

Answer (score 0):

If all the fields are same in both tables, you can try,

```
$table1 = Table1::find($id);
// Since $table1 is an object so you have to convert it into array bcs create accepts only array
$table1 = $table1->toArray();
// Also you will have id as autoincrement in table2 so you have to remove id of record of table1 before inserting to table2.
unset($table1['id']);
//Now insert array into table2
Table2::create($table1);
```